# Binding the parameters before setting the function pointer?

Tags: c++, bind, function-pointers, boost-bind, function-object

I would like to try something out and unify some boilerplate code in one of our dynamic library API wrappers.

Essentially, I would like to do the following:

```
typedef bool (*MyFPtrT)(long id, std::string const& name);
typedef boost::function<bool (long id, std::string const& name)> MyFObjT;
...

...
  MyFPtrT pDllFun = NULL;
  long x = 42; string s = "Answer"; // API input, not hardcoded
  MyFObjT f = boost::bind(pDllFun, x, s);
  ...
  return Call(f);
...

template<FT>
bool Call(FT f) {
  ...
  MyFPtrT pDllFun = (MyFunPtr)::GetProcAddress(...);
  f.setFunctionPointerButLeaveBoundParameters(pDllFun); // <- how??
  // Now call the correctly rigged up function object:
  return f();
}
```

Is this possible? (With Boost or otherwise?) (**C++03**)

Comment: I fear not possible...but lets wait for real answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done directly like that, because `bind` creates a new object that takes the function object and the arguments by reference, and you can't rebind references.

However, you can easily enough write your own templated functor wrapper with a reassignable function pointer:

```
template <typename R, typename A, typename B>
struct ReAssFunctor
{
  typedef R(*FP)(A, B);

  ReAssFunctor(const A & a_, const B & b_) a(a_), b(b_) { }

  R operator()() const { return func(a, b); }

  FP function;

private:
  const A & a;
  const B & b;
};
```

[Edit:] Do check the comments below; holding references taken by const reference in the constructor can be dangerously abused, so be careful, or save `a` and `b` by value if you prefer.[/]

Now you can initialize the functor with the arguments early:

```
ReAssFunctor<R, A, B> raf(a, b);
```

Then assign a function pointer and call:

```
raf.function = foo;
raf();

raf.function = goo;
raf();
```

You could even replace the call operator by this:

```
  template <typename U>
  U operator()(U (f*)(A, B)) const { return f(a, b); }
```

And then invoke the functor with the function pointer as the argument:

```
raf(fp1);  // calls fp1(a,b);
raf(fp2);  // calls fp2(a,b);
```

In that case you don't need the return type as a fixed parameter any longer, but now you don't get a nullary call operator. Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately, I have about 50 different functions to call this way, so I'd have to supply different templates for all arities.

Comment: **Note**: You should [never, ever initialize a member reference from a const-ref parameter](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/c561510cc7c53dc9)! (If I'd implement this I'd take a look at boost::function and just hold the `a` and `b` members by value.

Comment: @Martin: Interesting point. Doesn't holding a reference extend the lifetime of the temporary? I'm not sure the alternatives are better, though: Copying requires copyable arguments and may be expensive, and pointers (as suggested in the linked post) change the interface in an awkward way. Best would be to use C++0x and just make a deleted rvalue-reference overload!

Comment: No, lifetime is only extended for temporaries in the same local scope. As for copying: Boost.Bind also [internally copies its arguments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions) and they propose using `boost::[c]ref` should an actual reference be needed. As for pointers: Yes they would be awkward.

Comment: @Martin: I see - copying and optionally using `ref` (now also `std::ref`!) seems like a safer method. I'll add a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the following might work:

```
typedef bool (*MyFPtrT)(long id, std::string const& name);
typedef boost::function<bool (long id, std::string const& name)> MyFObjT;
...

...
  MyFPtrT pDllFun = NULL;
  long x = 42; string s = "Answer"; // API input, not hardcoded
  MyFObjT f = boost::bind(boost::ref(pDllFun), x, s);
  ...
  return Call(f, pDllFun);
...

template<class FT, class FP>
bool Call(FT f, FP& pDllFun) {
  pDllFun = (MyFunPtr)::GetProcAddress(...);
  return f();
}
```

Yeah, there are some dangerous references around there. In particular, `f` keeps a reference to `pDllFun`. This can be mitigated fairly easy: pack the two in a single class, so the lifetimes are obviously identical.